# Query: find rows that do not belong to a list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Lets consider I have a table 'Tab' which has a column 'Col'

The table 'Tab' has this data -

```
Col
1
2
3
4
5
```

If I have a set of values (2,3,6,7). I can query the values that are present in the table and the list by suing the query

```
Select Col from Tab where col IN (2,3,6,7)
```

But, if I want to return the values in the list that are not present in the table i.e. only (6,7) in this case. What query should I use?

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you on?

Comment: In comments you've appended to various answers, I see that you're dealing with string values, not integers, and that your input list contains somewhere in the neighborhood of 70 values.  Are you looking to write a stored procedure?  Using dynamically-generated SQL?  Parameterized query?  As Martin asked, what DB platform & version are you working with?  That will tell us what feature set we have to work with.  (XML, UDF, etc.)  Is Linq->SQL an option?

Comment: @Martin I am working on SQL Server 2005.
@Toby I am just trying to use a sql query to retrieve the rows that satisfy the conditions I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I believe is that your trying to find values from you in statement.  What you need to do is turn your in statement into a table and then you can determine which values are different.

```
create table #temp
(
value int
)

insert into #temp values 1
insert into #temp values 2
insert into #temp values 3
insert into #temp values 4

select
 id
from
 #temp
where
 not exists (select 1 from Tab where Col = id)
```

A better alternative would be to create a table-valued function to turn your comma-delimited string into a table.  I don't have any code handy, but it should be easy to find on Google.  In that case you would only need to use the syntax below.

```
select
 id
from
 dbo.SplitStringToTable('2,3,6,7')
where
 not exists (select 1 from Tab where Col = id)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I used an example here for simplicity. I actually am dealing with around 70 values. Writing 70 insert statements isn't really practical. I wonder if there is a simpler way to do this. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: How are you determining the values?

Comment: am sorry I added the comment before trying the latter part of your answer i.e. to create a table-valued function to turn comma separated string into a table. 

I tried this out now it gets simple once I get the list of values into a table. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

A SQL Server 2008 method

```
SELECT N FROM (VALUES(2),(3),(6),(7)) AS D (N)
EXCEPT
Select Col from Tab
```

Or SQL Server 2005

```
DECLARE @Values XML

SET @Values = 
'<r>
    <v>2</v>
    <v>3</v>
    <v>6</v>
    <v>7</v>
</r>' 


SELECT 
    vals.item.value('.[1]', 'INT') AS Val
FROM @Values.nodes('/r/v') vals(item)
EXCEPT
Select Col from Tab
```

Answer (score 2):

one way would be to use a temp table:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (i INT) 
INSERT @t1 VALUES(2) 
INSERT @t1 VALUES(3)
INSERT @t1 VALUES(6) 
INSERT @t1 VALUES(7)

SELECT i FROM @t1 WHERE i NOT IN (Select Col from Tab)
```

Comment: I used an example here for simplicity. I actually am dealing with around 70 values. Writing 70 insert statements isn't really practical. I wonder if there is a simpler way to do this.
Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One method is

```
declare @table table(col int)
insert into @table
select 1 union all
select 2  union all
select 3  union all
select 4  union all
select 5 


declare @t table(col int)
insert into @t
select 2 union all
select 3 union all
select 6 union all
select 7 

select t1.col from @t as t1 left join @table as t2 on t1.col=t2.col
where t2.col is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a [numbers] table in your database?  (See [Why should I consider using an auxiliary numbers table?](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html))

```
SELECT
    [Tab].*
FROM
    [numbers]
    LEFT JOIN [Tab]
        ON [numbers].[num] = [Tab].[Col]
WHERE
    [numbers].[num] IN (2, 3, 6, 7)
    AND [Tab].[Col] IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wasn't aware of this. But, I used an example here for simplicity. I actually am dealing with varchar and not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways to achive this, here is one.

```
SELECT a.col 
FROM 
  (SELECT 2 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7) AS a
WHERE a.col NOT IN (SELECT col FROM Tab)
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party...

```
SELECT 
    '2s' = SUM(CASE WHEN Tab.Col = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    '3s' = SUM(CASE WHEN Tab.Col = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    '6s' = SUM(CASE WHEN Tab.Col = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    '7s' = SUM(CASE WHEN Tab.Col = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
(SELECT 1 AS Col, 'Nums' = 1 UNION SELECT 2 AS Col,'Nums' = 1 UNION SELECT 3 AS Col,      'Nums' = 1 UNION SELECT 4 AS Col, 'Nums' = 1 UNION SELECT 5 AS Col, 'Nums' = 1 ) AS Tab
GROUP BY Tab.Nums
```

---

BTW, mine also gives counts of each, useful if you need it. Like if you were checking a product list against what you have in inventory. Though you can write a pivot for that better, just don't know how off the top of my head.