# SQlite3 query: find rows that do not belong to a list of values. optimization

Tags: sqlite

I just read a question that was eaxctly what i was looking for: 
[SO original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203534/query-find-rows-that-do-not-belong-to-a-list-of-values)

> Lets consider I have a table 'Tab' which has a column 'Col'
>
> The table 'Tab' has this data -
>
> ```
> Col
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> ```
>
> If I have a set of values (2,3,6,7). I can query the values that are
>   present in the table and the list by suing the query
>
> ```
> Select Col from Tab where col IN (2,3,6,7)
> ```
>
> But, if I want to return the values in the list that are not present
>   in the table i.e. only (6,7) in this case. What query should I use?

I've found several solutions involving creation of a temporary table, but the best one found there (at least the shorter, and i suppose the faster as well) is for SQL Server, and appear to me to not to work for SQLite3 as i need.

> A SQL Server 2008 method
>
> ```
> SELECT N FROM (VALUES(2),(3),(6),(7)) AS D (N)
> EXCEPT
> Select Col from Tab
> ```

is there any alternative way for SQLite 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, you can use `SELECT` without a `FROM` clause to return just one fixed record.
To get multiple records, combine those with `UNION ALL` (which is slightly faster than `UNION` because it doesn't check for duplicates):

```sql
SELECT 2 AS Col UNION ALL
SELECT 3        UNION ALL
SELECT 6        UNION ALL
SELECT 7                 
EXCEPT
SELECT Col FROM Tab
```

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for. Didn't think about UNION ALL. Thank you.